# Move SQL Server Database Files

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

My current environment is Always On with asynchronous mode with readable secondary's, but no failover. I wanted to move database file which is already in AG. But I can't failover AG. Please advise best possible way .

Comment: Can you remove the DBs from the secondary node, change le file location and then add them again ?

Comment: Thank you for the response Dominique. I will follow the same . remove db's from AG and move the files and then join them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

I had a very lengthy write-up on this. However, it turns out that SQLShack already has a great [walk-through](https://www.sqlshack.com/a-walk-through-of-moving-database-file-in-sql-server-always-on-availability-group/).

Without going into too much detail, here is a high level summary of what they suggest.

1. Connect to your secondary replica.
2. Remove the database from the Availaibly Group on the secondary replica. It should now show as Restoring.
3. Issue the move files command from the master database.
4. Stop the SQL service on the secondary replica.
5. move the files to the new location.
6. Start the SQL service
7. Check the file location in sys.master_files
8. Join the database back to the Availability Group.

Repeat for all remaining replicas. For your primary replica, you're going to need to failover.

If that's not an option, scrap the above method all together and do the following...

1. Remove the database from the Availability Group
2. Issue the move file command
3. Set the database to OFFLINE
4. Move the data and log files
5. Bring the database back ONLINE
6. Add the database back to the Availability Group.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Note that some people will need to restore any log files from the primary that were created after the database was removed from the secondary, on the secondary, to get the database caught up and able to be re-added to the AG.